# How can I access a particular element in an array of objects contained in JSON format using react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I've been given a json file(data.json) with the multiple objects within an array and would like to grab the value of a certain key in each of these objects. I'm using react redux to grab these values and then display them as a table on a webpage.

The following file is a simplified version of file, which has a lot more keys in each array element. This is why I'm not sure about using a
"state = {..." because I would have to list out too many elements.

```
{"state":"OK","display":"success","information":
[
    {"name":"North","type":"REGION"},
    {"name":"South","type":"REGION"},
    ....
```

The desired output would be on a webpage like so:

North
South
...
...

Comment: Can you share your Json or example, and what is the result you ask for

Comment: `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, pick one. I would recommend `reduce` because it has more functionality than all the other array methods.

Comment: Please update your question with all details. You give a desired output example but where and how do you want to plan to use this output? Where is the React part of your question? What have you tried up to now? Beside that, one can write a simple JS code to give you the desired output with a console.log. This is not what you want obviously. So, please give us more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to create a table using `name` properties. Here is a simple example.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
          "state": "OK",
          "display": "success",
          "information": [
            { "name": "North", "type": "REGION" },
            { "name": "South", "type": "REGION" },
          ],
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                {
                  this.state.information.map( el => 
                    <td>{el.name}</td>
                  )
                }
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("app")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```